# Spring integration : testing async flows

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm trying to write a test case for a scenario in which I send a message to a JMS endpoint and then the message is processed using Spring Integration. Here is a test case that works but its not entirely clear to me why it works. Here is the test:

```
public class MessageListenerTest {

@Autowired ApplicationContext context;
@Test
public void testEventListener() {
    SubscribableChannel eventsChannel = (SubscribableChannel) context.getBean("events");
    class TestMessageHandler implements MessageHandler {
        public Boolean received = false;
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            received = true;
        } 
    }
    TestMessageHandler handler = new TestMessageHandler();
    eventsChannel.subscribe(handler);
    PollableChannel outputChannel = new QueueChannel();
    PollingConsumer consumer = new PollingConsumer(outputChannel, handler);
    consumer.setBeanFactory(context);
    consumer.start();
    String msg = "hello world!";
    JmsTemplate template = (JmsTemplate) context.getBean("jmsTemplate");
    template.convertAndSend("myQueue", msg);
    outputChannel.receive(2000);
    Assert.assertTrue(handler.received);
}
}
```

This tests that the message sent to the queue is received. The message is received by a `SubscribableChannel` named `events`. What is not clear to me is how the `PollableChannel` is connected to the `SubscribableChannel`. Is it because of `TestMessageHandler`? If so, how? If this is working entirely by accident, it would be useful if someone could fix this or provide a simpler test case for this scenario.

**UPDATE**: Based on the suggestions in the comments, here is a modified test case:

```
public class MessageListenerTest {

@Autowired ApplicationContext context;

@Test
public void testEventListener() throws InterruptedException {
    SubscribableChannel eventsChannel = (SubscribableChannel) context.getBean("events");
    final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    MessageHandler handler = new MessageHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        } 
    };
    eventsChannel.subscribe(handler);
    String msg = "hello world!";
    JmsTemplate template = (JmsTemplate) context.getBean("jmsTemplate");
    template.convertAndSend("myQueue", msg);
    Assert.assertTrue(countDownLatch.await(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `outputChannel` just doesn't work. This channel is a test-case scope. so no one sends messages to it.

You can check that with the `assert`:

```
Assert.notNull(outputChannel.receive(2000));
```

It doesn't matter for how much channel the `MessageHandler` is subscribed. It just handles messages. So, it continues to handle messages from your `events`. And the binding to that inline `outputChannel` just is dead and doesn't matter for other application.

Comment: Thanks Artem. I did suspect that, but if I remove everything related to `outputChannel` the test fails. Is the presence of the polling consumer providing some kind of blocking that allows the test to pass?

Comment: Yes, your application is `async` and that your `outputChannel.receive(2000)` just blocks the test for 2 secs. If your message travels through the JMS form longer time, your test will fail again.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like a `Thread.sleep()` will work just as well. Is there a recommended way to test async stuff like this with Spring Integration? It looks like there must be some way to divert the flow from `events` and check the received message.

Comment: To pass the test you really should add the `CountDownLatch` for your test code and wait for it on the assert and `countDown()` it from `MessageHandler` code. In this case yes: you don't need `received` property any more :-)

Comment: Ah yes, a `CountDownLatch` would do the trick. Thanks for the tip!